# How do I pass an object to a callback of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Membership` model, and I have the following callback on it:

```
after_create :setup_connection, unless: Proc.new { self.connection_exists }
```

This is the method being called:

```
  def connection_exists
    Connection.where("membership_id = ? OR invited_membership_id = ?", self.id, self.id).count > 0 ? true : false
  end
```

But this is the query I want to run as that callback, but can't quite figure out how to pass the object to it I want.

```
Connection.where("invited_membership_id = ?", resource.id)
```

How do I get to pass the equivalent of `resource` or `user` into the callback that runs in an `after_create` on my `Membership` model?

Comment: Are a user and resource associated with a membership?

Comment: @BrentEicher Yes - but remember that this is the `after_create`.

Comment: When after_create is called, wouldn't a membership's associations already be set? Like it would know who it's user or resource is, and could thus call self.resource.id or supply it as an argument to connection_exists in the proc?

Comment: Oooh...yeh. You are correct @BrentEicher.

Comment: As a side note, never do this: `MyModel.where(foo).count > 0 ? true : false` (or even just `MyModel.where(foo).count > 0` which already returns a boolean—the ternary is redundant). Do this: [`MyModel.where(foo).exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) or just `MyModel.exists?(foo)`.

Comment: @Jordan What's the difference? Both seem to take similar time to execute, based on my trials at the console.

Comment: Adding logic when it serves no purpose is poor style whether its performance impact is huge or negligible.

Comment: Ok cool. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `after_create` callback the association is already set, you do not need to pass any object to the callback because your membership already knows who is its `resource` or `user`

```
Connection.where("invited_membership_id = ?", self.resource.id)
```